# Using 2D arrays with only one index

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
For f = 0 To n

       b(f + 1) = a(f)

    Next
```

Both "b" and "a" are integer arrays. I know that if "a" was a 1d array the code would work fine(without the "(f)"). Simply filling in B(f+1) with a(f). But if i use a 2d array i cant, even if i specify the first index. 
Obviously, VB wont allow using a 2d array with only one index.
Is there a way around this error?

Comment: Do you mean if b is a 2d array or if a is a 2d array?

Comment: I mean that "a" is a 2d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [**Jagged Array**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#BKMK_JaggedArrays).

The difference between a jagged array and a 2D array is that a *2D array* works just like a coordinate system, where each item is located at a specific x- and y-coordinate.

```
Array(3, 3):
        0  1  2  3
     0  A  B  C  D
     1  E  F  G  H
     2  I  J  K  L
     3  M  N  O  P
```

A *jagged array*, however, is ***an array of arrays***; meaning the main array only has one dimension, but it is capable of holding other arrays with their own size.

```
Array(3)(x):
         0   1   2   3   4
     0  {A,  B}
     1  {C,  D,  E,  F,  G}
     2  {H,  I,  J}
     3  {K}
```

Declaration example:

```
'A jagged array capable of holding 32 different 1D arrays.
Dim a As Integer()() = New Integer(32 - 1) {}
```

Initializing a sub-array:

```
'Initializes the first sub-array to hold 8 items.
a(0) = New Integer(8 - 1) {}
```

Accessing one item:

```
Dim b As Integer = a(1)(3) 'F
```

Accessing an entire array:

```
Dim b As Integer() = a(0) '{A, B}

b = a(1) '{C, D, E, F, G}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but when I try to fill an array on the jagged array, i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @MohamedYousef : You've got to initialize every contained array before you use it. For example: `a(0) = New Integer(8 - 1) {}` initializes the first array to hold 8 items (`a(0)(0)` through `a(0)(7)`).